# C++ using files, arrays, and counters

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifs

I have a homework question and I have finished most of it but im completely stuck now. The assignment is to read a file consisting of two columns of numbers, which represent how many seat are left for a concert and how many people bought tickets. ex:
120(capacity) 90(tickets bought)
140(capacity) 155(tickets bought)
The concert can be oversold so I need to read the file and figure out how many shows were:
under 70% full,
between 70% and 90% full,
between 90% and 100% full

ive loaded both columns into 2 arrays.
this is pieces of the code that are giving me trouble:

```
    int i=0;
int overbooked=0;
int denied=0;
int full70=0,full70_90=0,full=0,full90_100=0;  //where i declared the variables

full=((people[i]*100)/capacity[i]);  //my equation for finding out what percent each row is


      if(people[i] > capacity[i])                           
    overbooked++;
if(people[i] > capacity[i])
    denied++;
if(full < 70)
    full70++;
if (full >= 70 && full < 90)
    full70_90++;
if (full >=90 && full < 100)
    full90_100++;
```

what im having trouble with is the percentages because my counters are outputting to 0.
all i want to know is how do you keep count of every row. for example say that 5 rows are all below 70% full, how do I make sure it reads the whole file and adds to the counter after each one.

Comment: Have you learned about loops in your class? If so I would review them to see how they might be used here.

Comment: You've said, you've loaded both columns to arrays. That means you know how to use While or for loop. If you want count percentages, just loop (while or for cycle) over whole arrays and increment some counters as you've mentioned.

Comment: Your problem is integer math: `full=((people[i]*100)/capacity[i]);` Try this: `full=((people[i]*100.0)/capacity[i]);`